# Can we integrate protractor test with ALM (Quality center)

Tags: javascript, protractor, alm, hp-quality-center

Is there a way to integrate protractor test with HP ALM(Application lifecycle management). Purpose is to save the execution results in Quality center.

Is there a plug-in available for this?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/macroking/ALM-Integration This is written in python

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Agiletestware Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee), which is a commercial tool which allows you to integrate protractor+jasmine projects with ALM.
Please see docs: https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/ci-integration/jenkins/
You can also contact Agiletestware to get support on how to setup an integration

Disclaimer: I'm developing Bumblebee